# Interviewing during Sick Leave

Tags: interviewing, sickness

I have had a sleeping disorder that affected my performance during the last couple of years.

My employer allowed me to be late in the morning but I've always had the hardest tasks ever, and I would solve them in a way that restored client satisfaction (client was not happy before my coming).

My problem is that I've always been out of the loop, which impacted my health condition.

Now, I can't really work - not sure if I became work-a-phobic or something. Something is not right.

On top of being out of the loop, I've not been promoted nor did I get a raise - which is not normal in comparison to my peers contribution.

A couple of weeks ago, some colleagues (one from an old job) asked for my assistance, and I discovered that I was able to work. I've easily understood what they needed and was able to analyse the code ...

I believe my blockage is related to my current job.

My current employer doesn't want to get rid of me, maybe because, based on the experience of this company, they can't easily find good employees. But if they find one, they turn out to be limitedly skilled.

Since I've been approached in LinkedIn, is it risky to interview while in a sick leave? Is it hard for a potential employer to understand the aforementioned circumstances?

Or should I resign and start over?

Because I feel extremely motivated when I think of a new adventure.

Comment: I don't understand, why would sick leave affect interviewing?

Comment: They would assume I am not apt to work? Or spoiled boy?

Comment: Oh, so you are worried that if you describe your current situation they will assume that you are just lazy/spoiled/whatever? Why would you disclose that situation anyway? As a general rule say as little as you must about why leaving current employer, and whatever medical condition you may have is generally best left for the very end (or after signing). Which leads to a followup question: what country are you in? And is your condition a diagnosed disability (or whatever is equivalent of that in your country)?

Comment: I am not in the US. Physicians can't diagnose what I have, my sleep is interrupt at night and after many months, when it's time to wake up at 7 am, I close my eyes for 5 minutes and I wake up again it's 11 am. At the beginning of this problem, I was able to get up in time, but since I've been disappointed I got physically and mentally tired and I lost self control on myself I guess.

Comment: Where are you at then? The location matters greatly. And the reason I ask for diagnosis is because it's important whether this qualifies as disability.

Comment: I am in MENA region.

Comment: "*Should I?*" is not a question we can really answer. Can you shorten the question and identify what your core issue is? Changing jobs when you have a potential health problem? Keeping a good relationship with your current employer when you leave after being on sick leave? Something else? It's hard to answer questions that lack an actionable goal.

Comment: @Leonidas it is not clear if you are taking "one day" sick, or, are you away for (say) one whole week or more of sick leave? Pls explain

Answer (score 3):

You're asking if you can "get away" with doing an interview while on a **sick leave day**.

I'd probably say **don't do it**.

Why add complications and white-lies?

Instead, tell your current employer you have to take a personal day off (without pay if necessary) and then do the interview.

It's also extremely common to very simply interview after hours, say at 6. All interviewing companies realize you have a job currently.  It's normal.

Keep things simple and clear. Just interview after hours, or, simply take a personal day off.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong.  Interviewing after hours is not normal.  I've done one or two phone calls after hours, but in 20 years I've never done an after hour interview as an interviewer or interviewee.  An sick days and personal ays are the same thing.  Its your time off.  Just take it and do the interview.

Comment: Hi Gabe, perhaps it depends on the industry or field or such.  (I literally just interviewed someone out of hours!) Note that in - say - advertising the universal norm was to interview "sneakily" as it were after work, since everyone's a bit sensitive to moving around.  As I understand it (I have never worked in that field) in "Wall St" so to speak, they are also in to sneaky after-hours interviews.

Answer (score 2):

Your time off is your time off.  Your company has no right to say what you can and can't do on it.  Just go to the interview.